# How to convert an image from URL to Drawable

Tags: android, drawable

I'm having a problem converting an image to a `Drawable` object. I'm converting the image using:

```
public Drawable LoadImageFromWebOperations(String url) {
    try {
        InputStream is = (InputStream)new URL(url).getContent();
        Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "src name");
        return d;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exc=" + e);
        return null;
    }
}
```

I'm trying to put the `Drawable` in a `HashMap` and insert that into a `ListAdapter`, however the value of the `Drawable` always is something like  `android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@405359b0` instead of an integer and I get the message in logcat

> resolveUri failed on bad bitmap uri".

this is how I put the `Drawable` in the `HashMap`:

```
map.put("cover", String.valueOf(
    Main.this.LoadImageFromWebOperations("http://www.asdfasfs.com/dasfas.jpg")));
```

Comment: try instead this map.put("cover", Main.this.LoadImageFromWebOperations("http://www.asdfasfs.com/dasfas.jpg" ) );

Comment: this doesnt work, eclipse is saying: "The method put(String, String) in the type HashMap<String,String> is not applicable for the arguments (String, Drawable)"

Comment: Obviously you have to change the generic definition of your `HashMap`. It should be `HashMap<String, Drawable>`.

Comment: ive tried it but i keep getting errors, sorry i'm new to android...can you help me out? here is my full source http://paste2.org/p/1265573

Answer (score 2):

Why do you expect the drawable to be an integer? It is an object you can assign to an `imageView`.

There are items in your project you can refer to with their ID, that is true, but that is something else.

`R.drawable.icon` is not a `Drawable`, in the same sense that `R.view.your_Button` is not a `Button`. You would call something like `getViewFromId()` on that. If you have a function that works like this:

```
 doSomethingWithView(R.view.id);
```

Then it would not work with (pseudocode ofcourse)

```
 myView = new Button();
 doSomethingWithView(myView);
```

So if your function works with a `R.drawable.id`, it is highly unlikely that it works with a Drawable (except with overloading ofcourse).

Comment: The reason why i expect an integer is because String.valueOf("R.drawable.icon") returns a 10 digits integer. and map.put("cover","String.valueOf("R.drawable.icon")); works fine, but getting the drawable from URL doesnt

Comment: The value type of your HashMap should be Drawable, not String, then you can just lose the String.valueOf() completely. What do you that function does anyway? A Drawable is not a String and or an integer ... its a complex object.

Comment: This is because `R.drawable.icon` is just a _pointer_ to the actual Drawable.

Comment: I have updated the answer to reflect the confusion about the id's

Comment: hm so is there any simple solution that would work? here is the full source: http://paste2.org/p/1265573

Comment: Well, you should change your code so it can use drawables instead of ids. You'd have to change the simpleAdapter you're using, and you could not use a hashmap of 2 strings. I don't think its that hard, but can't give you the exact code from here. But technically it's changing the code to use a drawable instead of an id.

Comment: Hello robs could you please send me this could mmaidul.islam@gmail.com